# Unicode characters incorrect or missing with Puppeteer within Docker

Tags: docker, pdf, puppeteer

When I use puppeteer locally and produce a pdf, stock settings and headless, this character

is drawn correctly on the resulting pdf. When I try to run the same within Docker, the character renders incorrectly. This happens with many unicode chars within Docker, they render incorrectly or not at all.

I've read the posts about this, and it seems like it's a font problem? I have puppeteer running within docker, using node:16 as a base. Is it just that my base image doesn't have enough fonts? I've tried installing chrome and the other suggestions from the puppeteer docker file and related posts, they don't work. Using puppeteer 18.0.2 on node:16.

If it's a font issue, does somebody know how to get fonts installed that will work and produce the characters generally found in the headed browsers? Or is it something else? Ok, just posting this in 2022 since many of the answers from the past are old and outdated. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the official Docker image that pre-installs many fonts: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docker/Dockerfile#L11